# coding to check the data with array Intersect

Tags: php, arrays

I wanted to check to enter data into the database.Checks are as follows

```
$implode1 = "cat, dog, chicken";

$implode2 = "cow, goat, cat";
```

If the cat in the variable `$implode1` is also contained in the variable `$implode2`, it should display a warning message. How to code for the above problem?

Help me please :(

Comment: So you only want to enter unique items?

Comment: Better idea will be truncate all the occurencce of the string except one instead of throwing warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could [`explode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) your strings to arrays, then use [`array_intersect`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) to return the values which are present in both, eg:

```
$string1 = 'cat, dog, chicken';
$string2 = 'cow, goat, cat';

$compare = explode(', ', $string1);
$against = explode(', ', $string2);

$matches = array_intersect($compare, $against);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$implode1 = "cat, dog, chicken";
$implode2 = "cow, goat, cat";

$imp1 = explode(', ',$implode1);
$imp2 = explode(', ',$implode2);

foreach($imp1 as $val){
    if(in_array($val,$imp2)) {
        echo "$val is present in $implode2";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

loop the first array and check if any element is present in the second - something like this:

```
foreach($implode1 as $val){
if(in_array($val,$implode2)) {

    echo "$val is exists in the implode2 array";

       }
}
```

ohh, sorry, those are just strings. First explode them:

```
arr_implode1 = explode(", ",$implode1)
arr_implode1 = explode(", ",$implode2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just check before inserting the values into a database if they already exist:

```
if not exists (select * from TestTable where column NOT IN {$implode})
begin
    ...Do something here!!
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Create yourself a function that is able to extract the values out of each string in form of an array, then get the intersection. If it is not FALSE, there is an intersection, so do the warning:

```
$values = function($string) {
    return explode(', ', $string);
};

if (array_intersect($values($implode1), $values($implode2))) {
    trigger_error('Values intersect', E_USER_WARNING);
}
```

[See it in action](http://eval.in/2583).